# How to save/Manage Game Progress in Mobile devices (Unity)?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Currently I am saving game progress in a file in JSON format. Each time player completes the level a new entry will be added to JSON file as follow  `"level_N":{"score":234,"points":22},` 
this file will be saved at the end of Level complete. Consider scenario in which player reaches level 2345 or so, In that case saving to the file on level complete takes considerably longer time in some mobile devices. how to manage saving such a large amount of data ? do I have to use some other formats ? or do i have to save each level detail in separate file ?

Answer (score 1):

[PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) is the easiest way to save data. It’s designed to handle basic data types (int, string, float) and works like a dictionary, so you can simply store JSON string as key-value pairs. And there is no size limit on iOS or Android (in webplayer it's limited to 1MB).

```
// read
PlayerPrefs.GetString(string key, string value);

// write
PlayerPrefs.SetString(string key, string value);

// load and update
const saveKey = "level_N";
Private void SaveProgress() 
{
    string saveValue = "your JSON string"; 
    string loadValue = PlayerPrefs.GetString(saveKey); 
    if (!saveValue.Equals(loadValue)) 
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(saveKey, saveValue); 
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

User data will be automatically written to disk during OnApplicationQuit(), but you may want to use `PlayerPrefs.Save()` in case your game crashes.

Having said that, saving a large amount of data to PlayerPrefs on mobile devices might be slow. So if you want to improve your game performance or need more space, you can use [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) to save data to a public directory on the device. Similar to PlayerPrefs, data is not cleared when app is updated.

```
FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/gameInfo.dat", FileMode.Open);
```

Comment: `PlayerPrefs` are ment to store user **preferences** (therefore the name) like e.g. the sound volume and should **NOT** be used for storing important data like game progress as they might get deleted by updating the app!

Comment: @derHugo, So what do you recommend instead?

Comment: I would use your last section, a file in `Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "gameInfo.dat")` and read/write a properly encrypted file ;) or in a later step ofcourse an account based server

Comment: Keep in mind since the persistent data path is a public directory, users can acces their save data.

Comment: As others have said, PlayerPrefs is not used for this and you'll run into issues later on. JSON is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) class to save to save the local data.
In your case, you can trun your json to string then call PlayerPrefs.SetString to save/PlayerPrefs.GetString to get.

Comment: Can users reach and modify that string?

Comment: `PlayerPrefs` are ment to store user **preferences** (therefore the name) like e.g. the sound volume and should **NOT** be used for storing important data like game progress as they might get deleted by updating the app!

Comment: As others have said, PlayerPrefs is not used for this and you'll run into issues later on. JSON is fine.

Answer (score -2):

**PlayerPrefs** is always a good choice for local data managing but if you planning to add online features to your game, I recommend you to take a look at [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start) for sync json data with offline support. And let the firebase manage performance issues on mobile devices. [Here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/tree/master/database/testapp) you can see how to integrate Firebase Database to your Unity project easily.

Comment: `PlayerPrefs` are ment to store user **preferences** (therefore the name) like e.g. the sound volume and should **NOT** be used for storing important data like game progress as they might get deleted by updating the app!

Comment: As others have said, PlayerPrefs is not used for this and you'll run into issues later on. JSON is fine.